# 'INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: portal user email settings are not available' error on System.setPassword

Tags: customer-community

As stated in the title, I get this error when the System.setPassword method is called, but only in our production environment (while deploying, since it's called from test code too). So this leads me to believe there's an issue with our portal settings on this environment, but I have no clue where to look. Nothing I can find seems related to email settings not being available.

Comment: Does the user actually have access to any kind of portal or community? If he is not a member (via profile, permission set or otherwise) it will not be possible to reset password etc, and that button will not even appear on user detail page...

Answer (score 8):

The issue I ran into was that even though I had the right profiles assigned to the community, I had not yet published the community.

Comment: Indeed make sure you publish AND activate your community.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.  It turned out that the custom profile that I created was not assigned in the Community Settings.  In the community--> Administration --> Profiles, I selected the required profiles and saved.  Then it worked!